# Executing a block of code in apex class with context/visibility of a specific user

Tags: apex, visualforce, user, runas, context

I need to execute a block of code in apex class with context/visibility of a specific user. This user is mentioned in a custom field of a custom object. The need is similar to System.Runas() method however this method can be used only in test class not in apex class. 
Without using 'with sharing' apex class will run in system admin context and using 'with sharing' it will run with the context of user who invoked the transaction. However in my case it should be any of these two but a specific user.
Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Can that part of your code be run asynchronously? You have your question tagged with visualforce and mention a "class". Is this question about a "controller" for a visualforce page or perhaps a support class that it calls? If so, being more specific and providing sample code would be very helpful in getting an answer you'll find useful.

Comment: You need to be clearer -- Apex runs in system context - always - and ignores running user's CRUD privileges unless you specifically test for them with the `describe` calls.  `with sharing` and `without sharing` have to do with record visibility in the context of the running user. Inner classes can be used to enforce/relax this for a given operation.  Please clarify by using [edit] to amend your question